# Getting stream data from Kafka server to ReactJS frontend through Spring Boot backend

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, websocket

I am building a real-time system where clients produce a booking request from the NextJS frontend that (1) goes to the Spring Boot backend and (2) pushes a message to the Kafka server. I am able to (3) consume messages from the Kafka server using Spring Boot but am unsure how to (4) get this data back to the frontend

Code Excerpts:

(1) NodeJS to Spring Boot

```js
export async function sendBookingToKafka(message: string) {
    api.post('/api/v1/Kafka/producerMsg', {
        message: message,
    })
}
```

(2) Spring Boot to Kafka

```java
...[controller code]

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    kafkaTemplate.send("firsttopic", message);
}
```

(3) Consuming the data via Spring Boot

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "firsttopic", groupId = "my-first-application")
public void listenToTopic(String receivedMessage) {
    System.out.println("Received Message: " + receivedMessage);
}
```

(4) Reading the data from the frontend -- I need help here

I looked into web socket libraries like `Socket.io` and `ws` but it seems Spring Boot prefers `STOMP`. Most examples online reference the NPM library `stompjs` which has not been updated in nearly a decade so I want to refrain from using it. I have also looked at RabbitMQ through the `amqplib` NPM library or even `WebTransport` instead of WebSockets but am unsure whether it's appropriate to proceed with these as they seem unconventional relative to the information I'm finding online

Comment: You could just run Kafka REST Proxy or ksqlDB and poll their API... Do you really need websockets (or SSE) from Spring, or worry about managing SocketIO connections? For example, what happens if that socket disconnects, and the Kafka Consumer still consumes and commits an offset? Do you want every event? And how do you handle more than one frontend client when your backend is probably only using one consumer groupId (`my-first-application`)?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the answer - I looked into both resources but it doesn't seem possible to consume stream messages from the REST Proxy without a web socket. I think ksqlDB has the same issue too

Comment: Sorry I mean it's possible but polling the API seems inefficient for my use case where the events don't occur very frequently

Comment: `@KafkaListener` is also polling. You still need to make some repeated TCP connection. Even if you [use SSE](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events) (you don't need Websockets since you are only pushing data one direction)

Comment: https://tucanoo.com/integrating-apache-kafka-with-react-spring-boot-a-dockerized-tutorial/  shows how to hold the messages received by a listener until they are requested from your front end.  You could build on top of this and persist your messages with a timestamp, then just deliver back new items since the last pull.